# Запятая после ЧТО

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Бигиев считает, что(,) наряду с начальными школами, необходимы также средние и высшие учебные заведения,
По-моему, запятая в скобках не нужна. Так ли?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь обстоятельственный оборот(наряду с начальными школами), он обособляется факультативно.

В данном предложении нет смысла его выделять, поэтому запятые не ставим: Бигиев считает, что наряду с начальными школами необходимы также средние и высшие учебные заведения.

Правда, иногда действительно ставят одну запятую, но это неверно. Это как раз тот случай, когда паузу услышал и запятую поставил (даже есть такая проблема, которая называется "лишние запятые").